# Why cannot I find the cvPoint2D32f function in opencv?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I am using Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit) and OpenCv '2.4.13.2'. 
I am trying to apply geometrical transformation to images for which I need to use

```
CvPoint2D32f center = cvPoint2D32f(x, y)
```

but I am not able to find this function, is this not available in python or are deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type `CvPoint2D32f` is an older/deprecated type. OpenCV 2 introduced the type `Point2f` to replace it. Regardless, you don't need that type in Python. What you likely need is a numpy array with the `dtype = np.float32`. For points, the array should be constructed like:

```
points = np.array([ [[x1, y1]], ..., [[xn, yn]] ], dtype=np.float32)
```

You won't always need to set the `dtype`, as some functions (like `cv2.findHomography()` for example) will take integers.

For an example of these points being used, with the images from [this tutorial](http://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/), we could do the following to find and apply an homography to an image:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

src = cv2.imread('book2.jpg')
pts_src = np.array([[141, 131], [480, 159], [493, 630],[64, 601]], dtype=np.float32)
dst = cv2.imread('book1.jpg')
pts_dst = np.array([[318, 256],[534, 372],[316, 670],[73, 473]], dtype=np.float32)

transf = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts_src, pts_dst)
warped = cv2.warpPerspective(src, transf, (dst.shape[1],dst.shape[0]))

alpha = 0.5
beta = 1 - alpha
blended = cv2.addWeighted(warped, alpha, dst, beta, 1.0)

cv2.imshow("Blended Warped Image", blended)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Which will result in the following image:
[image: Warped image showing the output of a transformation.]